# Parsing Params out of a URL in Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am trying to track certain metrics in google analytics, but I only want to grab the params, remove sensitive information and send them off as a comma separated string. Such that:

```
this=me&that=you
```

would be fired off to ga as:

```
this,that
```

I have tried using Angular's native URL parser but I think I may need something more complex and I am not versed enough in REGEX to yank these out simply. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `.split('&')` and `.split('=')` to get the key-value pairs and then the parameters themselves.

Comment: ^ to tag on to that, you can also use `location.search` to get the parameters at the end of a url

Comment: Had to change something.  Take this with a grain of salt, but might give you some idea how to accomplish this with regex: \?((?<paramName>[\w-_\.%]+)=[\w-_\.%]+&?)+$

Comment: So in your example, would I just assign my string to 'paramName' and pass that into your regex?

Comment: Actually, that won't work in Javascript.  Check this out for a JS example: https://regex101.com/r/pN3uH3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `=` + values with commas, and then right-trim the final comma (if any) with regexps and `replace` in JS like this:

```js
var str = "this=me&that=you";
var result = str.replace(/=[^&]+(?:&|$)/g, ',').replace(/,$/,'');
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need more clarification on this.